# Isomorphism of irreducible R-modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let $R$ be a $k-$algebra and $M,N$ two irreducible $R-$modules, isomorphic as vector spaces. If we know that for every $r\in R$ we have the same eigenvalues on $M$ and $N$ (with multiplicities) is it true that $M\simeq N$?

I have two thoughts:

1. Denoting $St(m)=\{ rm=m \mid r\in R\}$, if we have $St(m)=St(n)$ for some $m\in M, n\in N$, we could find an isomorphism that sends $m$ to $n$ and is extended by $f(rm)=rf(m)$ (every element of $M$ is $rm$ for some $r$ by irreducibility). I cannot prove the existence of such a pair though.
2. If $R$ was commutative, we could simultaneously diagonalize all the actions according to some basis and take the isomorphism of vector spaces that sends the one basis to the other. This will then be an isomorphism of modules. I cannot extend that to the general case.

Comment: You mean the same eigenvalues corresponding to the same eigenvectors?

Comment: If $k$ is a field and $R$ is finite-dimensional over it then the actions on $M$ and $N$ factor through the quotient $R/J(R)$, which is semisimple. In the semisimple case it's easy to verify that this is true.

Comment: @Johannes: yes, that's why I wrote "if $k$ is a field and $R$ is finite-dimensional"...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Reading is not my strength it seems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $k$ is a field and $M$ and $N$ are finite-dimensional, then the answer is yes. That is part of (one version of) the Brauer-Nesbitt theorem. Having the same eigenvalues with the same algebraic multiplicities is equivalent to having the same characteristic polynomials.

For convenience define the characteristic polynomial of a $k$-linear endomorphism $\alpha:V\to V$ as $\chi_\alpha:=\det(1-T\alpha) \in k[T]$. The convenience is that $\chi_\alpha$ always has constant term 1 and therefore can be considered as an element of the multiplicative group $1+T\cdot k[[T]] \subseteq k[[T]]^\times$.

The Brauer-Nesbitt theorem then states more generally that the group homomorphism $\chi: G_0(R) \to (k[[T]]^\times)^R$ (where $G_0(R)$ is the Grothendieck group of finite-dimensional $R$-modules) induced by $[M]\mapsto(\chi_{r:M\to M})_{r\in R}$ is injective.

One can prove more: For example you don't need to have the characteristic polynomials for *all* elements of $r$, a $k$-basis is sufficient. For example the classic statement of Brauer-Nesbitt is that $G_0(kG) \to (k[[T]]^\times)^G$ is injective for finite groups $G$. This is a modular analogue of the characteristic-zero theorem that the character map $G_0(\mathbb{C}G) \to\mathbb{C}^G$ that comes from taking traces instead of characteristic polynomials is injective.

Using that $1+Tk[[T]]$ is the additive group of the Witt-ring of $k$ and playing around with the multiplicative structure on $W(k)$ one can even show that much smaller subsets than bases are also sufficient for injectivity.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually my question comes from equality of traces, but I am not at characteristic zero, the question is actually about p-adic groups. I used the equality of traces of $r, r^2, \ldots$ on both modules to conclude that the actual eigenvalues have to be equal. But is there a direct theorem that does not use the reduction on eigenvalues?

Comment: Also, because most references I can find are for more special cases, can you provide me with a reference to study the general theorem?

Comment: @IoannisZolas: The problem is that equality of all traces does *not* imply equality of all eigenvalues/char.polynomials. Not in positive characteristic anyway. Consider a module of the form $M^p$. Then every trace of every $r\in R$ is a multiple of $p$ and hence zero. But the eigenvalues are not all zero of course, they can be arbitrary in fact. They just happen to occur with multiplicity divisible by $p$.